# If you exceed your daily buying power, can you sell after market?

Tags: trading, margin

I have a margin account exceeding the required 25,000.

I exceeded my daily buying power to buy a stock. I got a message saying that if the positions are not held **overnight**, there would be restrictions placed on my account.

Does this mean:

1. It should only be sold after the market reopens tomorrow
2. It can be sold tomorrow before the market opens
3. It can be sold today after the market closes

Comment: What application or brokerage do you use? Is the message specific to that brokerage or generic to the exchange/country you're trading in?

Comment: I use TradeStation. I assumed it had to do with pattern day trader rules.

Comment: This is a good question. I suspect the answer is probably [here in the faq](https://www.tradestation.com/faqs/), or you can chat with the bot, or you could call them. (Which you may have to do anyway to lift the restriction if it happens.) And, you may be the best person to answer your own question if no one else does first.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but here are some examples of Trade Station [margin positions](http://help.tradestation.com/09_05/eng/tradestationhelp/buying_power/buy_power_ex.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different brokerage (eTrade), but I got *restricted* after selling in the evening (in your situation).

What counts is not ‘market close’ (which is really only one major market, not all of them), but *trading day*.

Comment: What defines a *trading day*?